# Using shortcuts (alias) in iOS

Tags: ios, alias, shortcut

In my game, rather than copying and pasting the existing images over and over again, I prefer to use shortcuts of images. However, each shortcut is 2.6mb which is bigger than most images. Is there a way to fix this issue? Cheers..

Comment: Do you mean a symlink? There's no such think as a 'shortcut' on *NIX systems.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Yes exactly.

Answer (score 4):

The full explanation is given in the Apple developer document "File System Programming Guide":

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH3-SW10

In short, what the original poster called a shortcut is properly called a bookmark; it is created using methods in class NSURL (or CFURL functions). When written to disk, it is called an alias file, as in the old days of the Mac. Filesystem bookmarks/alias files have a similar function to symbolic links, but they are far from being the same thing.

Symbolic links

- are provided at the Unix filesystem level
- contain no data other than a pathname
- are fragile if the destination file is moved
- require no application code to interpret, since the Unix kernel handles them

Alias files

- are specific to OS X, implemented by the Core Foundation and Foundation frameworks
- can be very large, especially when pointing to image data (on Mac as of OS X 10.7)
- are self-repairing if the destination file is moved (within certain limits)
- require the use of NSURL or CFURL routines to interpret

If you wish to create a Unix symlink from your code, use the symlink system call. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/symlink.2.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/2/symlink